# Is it Possible to Treat a Quadratic System of Equations as Linear to Show that the Equations are not Independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms, nonlinear-system

I have a system of $N$ equations with $n$ complex variables. Each equation has the form $a x_n^2 + b Re(x_nx_{n-1}) + ...+ c x_{n-1}^2 + d Re(x_{n-1}x_{n-2}) +...+ fx_1^2 = H$, where $H$ is a real number. For the question's sake, let's use $n=2$ and $N=4$. This will give us a system that looks like this:
$$ A_{11} x^2 + A_{12} xy\cos\eta + A_{13}y^2 = H_1$$
$$ A_{21} x^2 + A_{22} xy\cos\eta + A_{23}y^2 = H_2$$
$$ A_{31} x^2 + A_{32} xy\cos\eta + A_{33}y^2 = H_3$$
$$ A_{41} x^2 + A_{42} xy\cos\eta + A_{43}y^2 = H_4$$
My idea is that I can express the problem as:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} \\
A_{41} & A_{42} & A_{43} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
z_1 \\
z_2\\
z_3
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
H_1 \\
H_2\\
H_3 \\
H_4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Which now has the form $A \textbf{z}= H$. This form, I believe, allows me to test for linear independence by solving $A \textbf{z}= 0$. Is this line of thought correct?
Furthermore, I would like to add the following two conjectures:

1. *If the system of equations has infinitely many solutions, then the original quadratic system also has infinitely many solutions*.
2. *If the system of equations has a unique solution, then the original system of equations could have a finite set of solutions*

I am not sure how to test these conjectures. In my mind, I am thinking of this problem as a set of parabolic lines that may intersect. The question that I am answering by using the method above is whether the lines are on top of each other. This method doesn't tell me where they intersect.

Comment: I take it $z_1,z_2,z_3$ stand for $x^2,xy,y^2$ (though I don't know what $\eta$ is doing there). Note that the $z_i$ are not independent, since $z_1z_3=z_2^2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, the $z_i$ stand for that. The $\eta$ shows up since what I have is $Re(xy)$ and it would be the difference between the angle of the two complex numbers. Also, you are right that the middle column would be dependent on the other two columns. However, would it still be possible to show that the rows are independent?